# How to avoid typing a long series of variables

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

New to stackoverflow and fairly new to programming.

I have a set of 32 equations in 32 unknowns. I want to solve this equation using  `np.linalg.solve`:

for `a1 * x + b1 * y = c1` and `a2 * x + b2 * y = C2` (x and y are unknowns; a, b and c are variables coming from elsewhere in the program) this would look like:

```
eq1 = np.array([[a1,a2],[b1,b2]])
eq2 = np.array([c1,c2])
solution = np.linalg.solve(eq1,eq2)
```

In my case instead of having a and b, I have a 32x32 matrix holding all these variables in the form of q(i,j) and instead of c a 32x1 matrix in the form of p(i). This would look like this:

```
eq1 = np.array([[q(0,0),...,q(32,0)],...,[q(32,0),...,q(32,32)] 
eq2 = np.array([p(0),...,p(32)]
solution = np.linalg.solve(eq1,eq2)
```

which gets very long. I am looking for a way to avoid typing all this by hand. As far as I can see a dictionary doesn't help in this case, I'd still have to type out all the keys. I've read about things like `exec` (which seems to raise allergies for a lot of people) and `setattr` but these still don't solve it in my view... I tried a double loop to write q(i,j) as strings and concatenate all these strings into a long one, but I don't see how to return this into the original variables I need.

Is there any other way this could be done? I am not stuck to `np.alg.solve` if that simplifies a solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's q? A function? q(i, j) implies calling a function in Python.

Comment: `[q(0,0),...,q(32,0)],...,[q(32,0),...,q(32,32)]`. The first array looks like it is working it's way across the first row. The last array however looks like it is working across the last column. What order are you passing in these variables?

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Do you actually have a `q` function you can call? Is the data coming from a file you should parse? Do you just have a bunch of numbers on a piece of paper? This is crucial to answering the question. So far, everyone is assuming you have a `q` function.

Comment: My apologies, I should have used square brackets since `q` is an array of numbers calculated by an arithmetic expression. And idd I have writte the array wrongly. so all in all, it should have been:

`eq1 = np.array([[q[0,0],...,q[32,0]],...,[q[32,0],...,q[32,32]] 
eq2 = np.array([p[0],...,p[32]]
solution = np.linalg.solve(eq1,eq2)`

Again, sorry. I am used to Fortran (old crap, I know) where round brackets are used.

Comment: smac89's answer solved it. Thanks for your attention, all!

Answer (score 2):

#### What about:

```
eq1 = np.array([[q(i, j) for i in range(33)] for j in range(33)])
eq2 = np.array([p(i) for i in range(33)])
solution = np.linalg.solve(eq1,eq2)
```

Comment: That's probably what the OP wants :)

Comment: Incredible how easy it looks when you see it. This is it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You likely don't need literal integers as your indexes; a variable can do.

```
foo([x[i] for i in range(10)])
```

is an equivalent of

```
foo([x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8], x[9]])
```

Try adjusting the idea to your needs.

Note that you can reuse your long list of variables if needed:

```
piece = [x[i] for x in range(10, 20)]
baz = foo(piece) * bar(piece)
```